# How to create add-in which has a MENU in powerpoint using VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am working powerpoint 2007 and I want to create an add-in which has a dropdown list or some kind of menu so that user can select any one of them and the macros runs for that selection.

Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create this you can download a OfficeUIEditor and create a xml file with these program to create a ribbon.

Download [this pdf](http://ebook3000.com/RibbonX--Customizing-the-Office-2007-Ribbon_18257.html) it´s a good step by step to create and customize ribbons.

[]´s

Ps: [One more reference](http://www.rondebruin.nl/ribbon.htm)